# MySQL Rank, Cannot get it working properly

Tags: php, mysql, database, ranking, rank

I know this has been covered somewhat but it hasn't helped my situation, rather there's been discrepancies in the rank. Wondering if anyone would be able to help!

So i have a game, the database tables are:
users, maps, nicknames, user_game_scores

Im developing a leader board and easily able to get the information ordered by score. fantastic.

But i want to rank this so that i can pull a specific users scores and the rank be relevant to all scores. eg:

GLOBAL SCORES

```
user info - Score - (rank)1
user info - Score - (rank)2
user info - Score - (rank)3
etc.
```

Whereas USER SCORES are more likely to be:

```
user info - Score - (rank)82
user info - Score - (rank)94
user info - Score - (rank)115
etc.
```

I imagine the implementation to be this:

```
 SELECT users.first_name, users.surname, player_nicknames.nickname, maps.map_name, user_game_scores.score,
FIND_IN_SET( score, ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score ORDER BY score DESC ) FROM user_game_scores ) ) AS rank
FROM `user_game_scores`
INNER JOIN users ON user_game_scores.user_id = users.user_id
INNER JOIN maps ON user_game_scores.map_id = maps.map_id
INNER JOIN player_nicknames ON user_game_scores.user_id = player_nicknames.user_id
WHERE user_game_scores.deleted is null
AND users.deleted is null
AND player_nicknames.deleted is null
ORDER BY user_game_scores.score DESC
```

[But it returns this: (click here) - names etc have been removed from the image as it may not be appropriate to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRWVE.png)
As you can see the Rank tends to miss a number or two (number 2 and 23). i understand that something like rank 24 will group and continue (which i prefer to happen in that instance) but i dont understand why some of the rank is missing and really dont want to post process this functionality.

Sorry this is long but i thought id provide as much information as i can. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: It's probably because your `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT` subquery doesn't filter "deleted" (`deleted is null`) entries.

Comment: You sir, are amazing.

It was actually that another record had been deleted but i hadn't cleared the entry from this table.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your SELECT GROUP_CONCAT subquery doesn't filter "deleted" (deleted is null) entries. – Paul Spiegel 9 hours ago